# How do I get count of what would be returned by Hibernate query object?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a chunk of code that gets handed an arbitrary org.hibernate.Query object. This query is not a 'count' query. How do I get the number of items that would be returned from that query without pulling apart the sql string from the query?

I ran across the org.hibernate.Criteria object in my research for this problem, which does have the `setProjection(Projections.rowCount())` method. But I was unable to find a way to convert the Query object into a Criteria object or find a similar method for the Query object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without using Projections, or pulling apart the Query, I'm not sure of how you would have it also return the count.    
Is there a reason you can't call .size() on the return? Unless I am misunderstanding what is being done.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid actually getting the objects from the database. There may be many results and from what I can tell, the `list()` method doesn't return a cursor, but a populated list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Query.scroll()`, got to the last position using `ScrollableResults.last()`, and call `getRowNumber()`.

Note though that this will give you the number of SQL rows, and not necessarily the number of entities returned by the query (if there is a join fetch on a collection, for example).

Comment: Since the query would most likely be to filter the results, the actual number that would be returned by the query would be needed.